# groupby not grouping string together eventhough they are exactly same

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

groupby has always worked for me, but in the Dataframe I am dealing with I have a column named "ID" which has the id and "text" which holds the text for each page of a fax:

```
 ID                       text                  page

210128_ABC8476583   |     text for page 1    |     1  
210128_ABC8476583   |     text for page 2    |     2
210128_ABC8476583   |     text for page 3    |     3
210128_ABC8476583   |     text for page 4    |     4
210324_ABC9476037   |     text for page 1    |     1
.....
```

I am trying to do a simple `df.groupby("ID")` but it basically returns the exact same dataframe(no grouping of similar IDs). the ID and text are of type "String" and page is "`numpy.int64`". I am not getting any errors and the result is a `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy`

my code is something like this:

```
id_test = ids.groupby("ID")
id_test[["ID", "text", "page"]].head()
```

what am I doing wrong?

*ids is the name of the dataframe I am working with

Comment: How could you be dealing with fax in 2021? ;)

Comment: Will you please add the output of `print(ids.head().to_dict())` to the question?

Answer (score 0):

`df.groupby()` always returns such a `DataFrameGroupBy` object. You need to call some method on that object to specify how to aggregate the values in the other columns. Then you'll get a grouped dataframe.

It's not clear from the question what you expect the output to be, so it's hard to make a suggestion as to  what aggregation method to use. Maybe concatenate all the pages in the `text` column and use `max()` for the `page` column?

You can pass a dictionary to the `agg()` method to choose a different aggregation function for each column, e.g.:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['210128_ABC8476583', '210128_ABC8476583',
                          '210128_ABC8476583', '210128_ABC8476583',
                          '210324_ABC9476037'],
                   'text': ['text for page 1', 'text for page 2',
                            'text for page 3', 'text for page 4',
                            'text for page 1'],
                   'page': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]})

df.groupby('ID').agg({'text': ' NEW PAGE '.join,
                      'page': max})
```

```
                    text                                                page
ID      
210128_ABC8476583   text for page 1 NEW PAGE text for page 2 NEW P...   4
210324_ABC9476037   text for page 1                                     1
```

Comment: I was expecting to have each ID mentioned once and all of its pages in the next column and then the next ID after that and all of its pages in the column next to it so I can export to excel

Comment: Isn't that what I did above? You can of course delete the `page` column from the result.